# How to find the present working directory drive letter using Property function in Msbuild?

Tags: c#, msbuild, msbuild-4.0

I have a property like below

```
<DynamicViewDrive Condition="'$(DynamicViewDrive)' == ''">U:</DynamicViewDrive>
```

Whenever i am changing my folder apart from U: drive , I have to edit this property.

How to get the current drive letter using Propertyfunction in Msbuild?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would be the drive letter of the of current project file:

```
<Drive Condition=" '$(Drive)' == '' ">$([System.IO.Path]::GetPathRoot($(MSBuildProjectFullPath)))</Drive>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the old style way to do this, this time using an item not a property.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="ShowDrive" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup>
        <Drive Include="$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)"/>
    </ItemGroup>    

    <Target Name="ShowDrive">
        <Message Text="Drive: %(Drive.RootDir)"/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

This way you can use other [Well known item metadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164313.aspx) from the MSBuildProjectFullPath property if necessary.